# How to Get Text Node with Dojo JS

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I am trying to get the text from within a tag - but that tag has a nested node, too which I don't want. How do I just get the text?

For example

```
<div id="i_want_the_text_in_this_div">
  <span id="but_not_this_one">
   ignore this text
  </span> 
  keep this text
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dojo.attr(node, 'innerHTML')` as `textContent` does not work in IE

Comment: If you get the node through dojo textContent does seem to work in the latest IE

Answer (score 7):

Try: `dojo.query('#i_want_the_text_in_this_div')[0].lastChild.textContent;`